# Converting an array to hash in ruby

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash

Supposed I have an array that looks like

```
testarr = [["Actor", "Morgan", "33", ["A","B"]],
  ["Movie", "Titanic", "44", ["A","A"]],
  ["Actor", "Jack Black", "333", ["A","A"]]]
```

I want to convert this into a hash which will be converted into a json eventually.

I want it to look like

```
{

    "Actor" => { 
           {   "name" : "Morgan",
               "Age" : 33",
               "Films: { "A", "B" }} ,

           {   "name" : "Jack Black",
               "Age" : 44",
               "Films: { "A", "A" }}
           }
    "Movie" => {
           {    "Title" : "Titanic"
                "Gross" : "44"
                "Actors" : { "A", "A" }
           }
     }
```

Not sure about the exact format, but whatever makes sense.

I tried

```
def hashing(arr)
 hash = Hash.new

 arr.each do |item|

     if item[0] == "Movie"
       item.delete("Movie")
       hash["Movie"] = item
       item["Title"] = item[1]
       item["Movie"]["Box Office"] = item[2]
       item["Movie"]["Actors"] = item[3]

     else

        item.delete("Actor")
        hash["Actor"] = item

        item["Actor"]["Name"] == item[1]
        item["Actor"]["Age"] == item[2]
        item["Actor"]["Filmography"] == item[3]

     end

   end

  return hash

end

testarr = [["Actor", "Morgan", "33", ["dsfds","dsfdsf"]],
  ["Movie", "Titanic", "44", ["dsfds","dfdsf"]],
  ["Actor", "Jack Black", "333", ["ssdsfds","dsfdsf"]]]

puts hashing(testarr)
```

But it gives me an error for putting the array item into "Movie" and "Actor" then trying to create keys like "Name" and "Age".

How can I make this as I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
testarr = [["Actor", "Morgan", "33", ["A","B"]],
  ["Movie", "Titanic", "44", ["A","A"]],
  ["Actor", "Jack Black", "333", ["A","A"]]]

  a = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = [] }

  testarr.each do |arr|
    b = {name: arr[1], age: arr[2], films: arr[3]}
    a[arr[0]] << b
  end
```

this will produce

```
{"Actor"=>[{"name"=>"Morgan", "age"=>"33", "films"=>["A", "B"]}, {"name"=>"Jack Black", "age"=>"333", "films"=>["A", "A"]}], "Movie"=>[{"name"=>"Titanic", "age"=>"44", "films"=>["A", "A"]}]}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I actually put Age and Filmography of an Actor inside the name key? Like Name => Morgan => { Age: 33, Filmo = [...] }

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code,

```
v = [["Actor", "Morgan", "33", ["A", "B"]], ["Movie", "Titanic", "44", ["A", "A"]], ["Actor", "Jack Black", "333", ["A", "A"]]]

v.inject({}) do |ot, arr|
  item = {name: arr[1], age: arr[2], films: arr[3]}
  if ot[arr[0]].present?
    ot[arr[0]] << item
  else
    ot[arr[0]] = []
    ot[arr[0]] << item
  end
  ot
end
```

And the o/p is like below,

```
# => {"Actor"=>[{:name=>"Morgan", :age=>"33", :films=>["A", "B"]}, {:name=>"Jack Black", :age=>"333", :films=>["A", "A"]}], "Movie"=>[{:name=>"Titanic", :age=>"44", :films=>["A", "A"]}]}
```

Please note here the **Actor** is not hash of hashes, it's array of hashes, this is the standard way of keeping collection and convert it to json if you need by using **to_json** method.

Comment: Thanks! But I get a undefined method `present?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError). Is that a valid method?

Comment: Yes, it;s rails standard method. Are you using Rails or not?

Comment: I'm using regular ruby

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the array and parse each item, appending it to the resultant hash.

```
testarr = [["Actor", "Morgan", "33", ["A", "B"]],
           ["Movie", "Titanic", "44", ["A", "A"]],
           ["Actor", "Jack Black", "333", ["A", "A"]]]

results = {}

testarr.each do |item|
  key, a, b, c = item
  r = if key == 'Actor'
        { name: a, age: b, movies: c }
      elsif key == 'Movie'
        { title: a, gross: b, actors: c }
      end
  results[key] = [] unless results[key]
  results[key] << r
end

puts results
```

This will produce:

```
{"Actor"=>[{:name=>"Morgan", :age=>"33", :movies=>["A", "B"]}, {:name=>"Jack Black", :age=>"333", :movies=>["A", "A"]}], "Movie"=>[{:title=>"Titanic", :gross=>"44", :actors=>["A", "A"]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value in your `:actor` contains a hash without a key. The best thing you can do is put that into an array.

This will work. There might be a cleaner way, but I'm not sure how at the moment:

```rb
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
testarr = [["Actor", "Morgan", "33", ["A", "B"]], ["Movie", "Titanic", "44", ["A", "A"]], ["Actor", "Jack Black", "333", ["A", "A"]]]

testarr.each do |t|
  if t[0] == 'Movie'
    h[t[0]] << {title: t[1], gross: t[2], actors: t[3]}
  else
    h[t[0]] << {name: t[1], age: t[2], films: t[3]}
  end
end

puts h
```

**Output:**

```rb
{"Actor"=>[{:name=>"Morgan", :age=>"33", :films=>["A", "B"]}, {:name=>"Jack Black", :age=>"333", :films=>["A", "A"]}], "Movie"=>[{:title=>"Titanic", :gross=>"44", :actors=>["A", "A"]}]}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I actually put Age and Filmography of an Actor inside the name key? Like Name => Morgan => { Age: 33, Filmo = [...] }

Answer (score 1):

I tried to keep the example you wrote.

First of all, it must be shaped for Array(such as  `[a, b]` ) not Hash( `{a, b}` ) list of items

```
# You may want result like this ...
{
    "Actor": [    # not '{' but '['
        {
            "name": "Morgan",
            "Age": "33",
            "Films": ["A", "B"]    # not '{' but '[' also
        },
        {
            "name": "Jack Black",
            "Age": "44",
            "Films": ["A", "A"]
        }
    ],
    "Movie": [
        {
            "Title": "Titanic",
            "Gross": "44",
            "Actors": ["A", "A"]
        }
    ]
}
```

and then your function should be like this ...

```
def hashing(arr)
    hash = Hash.new
    hash["Movie"], hash["Actor"] = [], []

    arr.each do |item|

        if item[0] == "Movie"
            movie = {}
            movie["Title"]      = item[1]
            movie["Box Office"] = item[2]
            movie["Actors"]     = item[3]

            item.delete("Movie")         # optional
            hash["Movie"] << movie

        else
            actor = {}
            actor["Name"]           = item[1]
            actor["Age"]            = item[2]
            actor["Filmography"]    = item[3]

            item.delete("Actor")         # optional
            hash["Actor"] << actor
        end

    end

    return hash
end
```

Then it's time to test!
as your codes,

```
testarr = [
    ["Actor", "Morgan", "33", ["dsfds","dsfdsf"]],
    ["Movie", "Titanic", "44", ["dsfds","dfdsf"]],
    ["Actor", "Jack Black", "333", ["ssdsfds","dsfdsf"]]
]

puts hashing(testarr)
```

It will return this:

```
{
  "Movie"=>
    [
      {"Title"=>"Titanic", "Box Office"=>"44", "Actors"=>["dsfds", "dfdsf"]}
    ],
  "Actor"=>
    [
      {"Name"=>"Morgan", "Age"=>"33", "Filmography"=>["dsfds", "dsfdsf"]},
      {"Name"=>"Jack Black", "Age"=>"333", "Filmography"=>["ssdsfds", "dsfdsf"]}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I actually put Age and Filmography of an Actor inside the name key? Like Name => Morgan => { Age: 33, Filmo = [...] }

Comment: Simple! Wrap your structure once more. in your expression, `Name => Morgan => {...} ` goes with wrapper like `Name => { Morgan => {...} }`. All of your keys in structure, must have whole under structure for value such like what i wrap. By the way, i suggest original one rather than new one for protecting and defining objects more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def convert(arr, keys)
  arr.group_by(&:first).transform_values do |a|
    a.map { |key, *values| keys[key].zip(values).to_h }
  end
end
```

**Example (using `testarr` defined in the question)**

```
keys = { "Actor"=>[:name, :Age, :Films], "Movie"=>[:Title, :Gross, :Actors] }

convert(testarr, keys)
  #=> { "Actor"=>[
  #       {:name=>"Morgan", :Age=>"33", :Films=>["A", "B"]},
  #       {:name=>"Jack Black", :Age=>"333", :Films=>["A", "A"]}
  #     ],
  #     "Movie"=>[
  #      {:Title=>"Titanic", :Gross=>"44", :Actors=>["A", "A"]}
  #     ]
  #   }
```

**Explanation**

See [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values), [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h).

The steps are as follows.

```
h = testarr.group_by(&:first)
  #=> { "Actor"=>[
  #       ["Actor", "Morgan", "33", ["A", "B"]],
  #       ["Actor", "Jack Black", "333", ["A", "A"]]
  #     ],
  #     "Movie"=>[
  #       ["Movie", "Titanic", "44", ["A", "A"]]
  #     ]
  #   }
```

Though not quite equivalent, you can think of `testarr.group_by(&:first)` as being "shorthand" for `testarr.group_by { |a| a.first }`. Continuing,

```
e0 = h.transform_values
  #=> #<Enumerator:
  #   {"Actor"=>[["Actor", "Morgan", "33", ["A", "B"]],
  #              ["Actor", "Jack Black", "333", ["A", "A"]]],
  #    "Movie"=>[["Movie", "Titanic", "44", ["A", "A"]]]}
  #  :transform_values>
```

The first element is generated by the enumerator `e0`, passed to the block and the block variable is set equal to that value.

```
a = e0.next
  #=> [["Actor", "Morgan", "33", ["A", "B"]],
  #    ["Actor", "Jack Black", "333", ["A", "A"]]]
```

A second enumerator is now created.

```
e1 = a.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["Actor", "Morgan", "33", ["A", "B"]],
  #                  ["Actor", "Jack Black", "333", ["A", "A"]]]:map>
```

The first value is generated by `e1`, passed to the inner block and the block variables are assigned values (using *disambiguation*).

```
key, *values = e1.next
  #=> ["Actor", "Morgan", "33", ["A", "B"]]
key
  #=> "Actor"
values
  #=> ["Morgan", "33", ["A", "B"]]
```

The inner block calculation is now performed.

```
b = keys[key].zip(values)
  #=> keys["Actor"].zip(["Morgan", "33", ["A", "B"]])
  #=> [:name, :Age, :Films].zip(["Morgan", "33", ["A", "B"]])
  #=> [[:name, "Morgan"], [:Age, "33"], [:Films, ["A", "B"]]]
b.to_h
  #=> {:name=>"Morgan", :Age=>"33", :Films=>["A", "B"]}
```

Now the second and last element is generated by `e1` and the same calculations are performed.

```
key, *values = e1.next
  #=> ["Actor", "Jack Black", "333", ["A", "A"]]
b = keys[key].zip(values)
  #=> [[:name, "Jack Black"], [:Age, "333"], [:Films, ["A", "A"]]]
b.to_h
  #=> {:name=>"Jack Black", :Age=>"333", :Films=>["A", "A"]}
```

When another value is sought from `e1` we obtain the following.

```
e1.next
  #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

This exception is caught, causing `e1` to return to the outer block. At this point `e0` generates it next (and last value).

```
a = e0.next
  #=> [["Movie", "Titanic", "44", ["A", "A"]]]
```

The remaining calculations are similar.